# Opencpu webhook for private Github repo doesn't work

Tags: r, docker, github, webhooks, opencpu

I setup an OpenCPU server (running in a container) and tried to deploy some R repos from GitHub using webhooks. That works nicely when repo is public, but when private I've got this response: `Failed to read https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/DESCRIPTION. Repsitory does not contain a proper R package`.

That url must have a `token` when private, but how to fix it on server?

Attempts:

- auth_token in the Payload URL: https://ocpu.domain.com/ocpu/webhook?sendmail=false&auth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
- auth_token in /etc/opencpu/secret.conf
- GITHUB_PAT in .Renviron file
- SSH key

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks that may be a bug. As a workaround try setting `GITHUB_PAT` in `/etc/opencpu/Renviron`

Comment: Can you open an issue on Github?

Comment: HI @Jeroen, tried also in /etc/opencpu/Renviron and didn't work. Ok. Thanks.

Comment: OK this is definitely a bug. Fixing this for the 2.0.6 release.

Comment: Works like a charm in the v2.0.6 with the auth_token param.

Example: https://ocpu.domain.com/ocpu/webhook?sendmail=false&auth_token="xxxxxxx"

Thank you.